# Vector set of all real functions and its basis

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In our linear algebra lectures, we proved that for any vector space $V$ over some field $\Bbb F$, there is a basis that contains no vector from a base of its subspace $M$.
I was thinking about a vector space $\mathcal C(\Bbb R)$of all real continuous functions. A function can be: even $\underline{\vee}$ odd $\underline{\vee}$ neither even nor odd.

Every even function can be written as a sum of an even and an odd function.
Every odd function can be written as a difference of an even and an odd function.

When constructing a base for $\mathcal C(\mathbb R)$, I wanted to use even functions and some that are neither even nor odd.

Let $E$ be a space of all even functions in $\mathcal C(\mathbb R)$, O space of all odd functions in $\mathcal C(\mathbb R)$ an $W$ space of the rest of the functions in $\mathcal C(\mathbb R)$.
$$\dim{\mathcal C(\mathbb R)}=\aleph_0 ?$$

Let $f$ be some arbitrary even function, $f_e \in E, f_o \in O, f_w \in W.$
Then: $$f_i=f_{e_i}+f_{o_i}$$

My greatest difficulty is that $\mathbb R$ is uncountably infinite, so my index might be nonsense.

My base for $\mathcal C(\Bbb R)$ would look like this:
$$\{(x_i,x_i',\ldots,y_i,y_i',\ldots):x_i=f_{e_i}+f_{o_i},y_i=f_{w_i},i\in I, |I|=|\Bbb R|\}$$

Does this have any sense?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ is the space of all functions $\mathbb{R}\mapsto \mathbb{R}$. The space of all continuous function $\mathbb{R}\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is usually written $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: The "space" of all odd functions is **not** a vector suspace of what you calll $\;\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}\;$ ...but the set of all even continuous functions **is** a subspace...and $\;\dim C(\Bbb R)=2^{\aleph_0}\;$ , not merely $\;\aleph_0\;$

Comment: Thank you for correction.

Comment: "Every even function can be written as a sum of an even and an odd function." but only if the odd function is $\equiv 0$. -- "Every odd function can be written as a difference of an even and an odd function." but only if the even function is $\equiv 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with what you're trying to achieve is that the existence of a basis for $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R})$ relies on the axiom of choice, which isn't constructive. While such bases do exist, it is **extremely hard** to provide one explicitly.

As for the cardinality of such a basis, it is $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: Merely "extremely hard" or impossible?

Comment: @badjohn As far as I'm concerned, impossible.

Comment: I'm not an expert here but I thought that it was impossible.  So, I might also have played safe and phrased it as you did.